# Notification when new comments are posted on my blog

Tags: wordpress, notifications, comments

I'm an admin user of my own blog. There was a comment posted on my blog months ago and I know nothing about it until today when I accidentally opened the comments manager in WordPress.

How can I get myself notified by email when new comment is posted? At the moment, new posted comments are notified to users/me only after they are approved (by admin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to change the setting in your blog 
Follow here: http://en.support.wordpress.com/comment-notification-email/

Answer (score 2):

For a quick and geneal solution, you could give [feedmyinbox](http://www.feedmyinbox.com/) a go. It lets you set up email alerts for any RSS feed. Your wordpress blog offers comment RSS feeds out of the box.

Comment: And you could configure it to work with your comments RSS feed

Comment: @thunderror: yup, that was the implication! I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

How about this: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/notify-on-comment/ ?

Comment: Can't add plugins at wordpress.com

Comment: One more reason to go for a self-hosted blog

Comment: I'm looking for solution for wordpress.com (WordPress hosted) not wordpress.org (self-hosted). Thanks anyway.